# php Foreach for an array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I didnt know what title to use because this is quite an unusual situation. Please let me explain. I have a site with multiple pages and each one have different metatags such as title, description and keywords. So i made this code:

```
define('title', 0);
define('keywords', 1);
define('desc', 2);

$tags = array(
    'index'    => array('My site', 'php, tricks', 'My site about php'),    
    'about'    => array('About', 'etc, about', 'About this site'),
    'other'    => array('Other', 'some, shit', 'Some other shit')
);
```

My site pages look like this: `mysite.com/index`, `mysite.com/about`, etc. and thus, i have a directory with all those pages which are named `index.php`, `about.php` and so on. So if i want to add a new page called contact, i must create a file named `contact.php` and add a new line into my array like this:

```
$tags = array(
    'index'    => array('My site', 'php, tricks', 'My site about php'),    
    'about'    => array('About', 'etc, about', 'About this site'),
    'other'    => array('Other', 'some, shit', 'Some other shit'),
    'contact'  => array('Contact', 'contact, whatever', 'Contact form')
);
```

This works fine so far. However, now i have a group of pages that start all with `column-` and i want them to automatically add their tags without having to add any more lines to the code. Something like this:

```
$tags = array(
    'index'    => array('My site', 'php, tricks', 'My site about php'),    
    'about'    => array('About', 'etc, about', 'About this site'),
    'other'    => array('Other', 'some, shit', 'Some other shit'),
    $column_pages  => array($col_title, $col_keywords, $col_desc)
);
```

I guess i should scan my directory for the files to get the names first and then filter those ones that start with "column-":

```
$column_page = scandir("content");
foreach ($column_page as $value) {
  if(preg_match("/column/i", $value)) {
     $column_pages = $value;
  }
}
```

but after this im kinda stuck and i dont have idea how to go any further. What should i do now?

**What i need is** , to put it in clear words, I want to scan all file names inside a specific folder/directory,check if its name starts with `column-` and then generate the attributes automatically with the help of `PHP`

**For example**, Assuming that as of now i have 3 files starting with "column-" which are: 
 `column-news`, `column-variety` and `column-radio`; my expected result is something that works exactly like this code below:

```
$tags = array(
    'index'    => array('My site', 'php, tricks', 'My site about php'),    
    'about'    => array('About', 'etc, about', 'About this site'),
    'other'    => array('Other', 'some, shit', 'Some other shit'),
    'column-news'  => array('News', 'some, news', 'Column with news'),
    'column-variety'  => array('News', 'some, variety', 'Column with variety'),
    'column-radio'  => array('News', 'some, radio', 'Column with radio')
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: so exactly what are you looking for...? where are you stucked, thats unclear!

Comment: Im stuck at this point because i cant go any further. The variable $column_pages should generate the names for all the files whose name start with column-

Comment: I edited my question and now its even clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it

- scan all directories
- do `regex` match for pattern in file name
- store in array if match found

Code

```
$pattern = "/^column-*/i" //i for making it case insensitive, ^ denotes start of name
$path = "some/dir/path/";
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as $file_name) {
    if(preg_match($pattern, $file_name){
        $column_pieces = explode("-", $file_name);
        $tags = array($file_name  => 
                        array($column_pieces[0], $column_pieces[1], $column_pieces[2])
                      );
    }
}
```

In this line of code :

```
$tags = array($file_name  => 
                            array($column_pieces[0], $column_pieces[1], $column_pieces[2])
                          );
```

`$file_name` would be your key and `$column_pieces[XX]` is optional only to show you how it would be done, you can have other details saved in it which you might fetch from DB

Comment: Im afraid i dont understand. How do i store in array?

Comment: I see but what about the files that dont start with column-?

Comment: what is the naming convention you are following in the directory??If it works, just use `column` instead of `column-` :)

Comment: So far i was naming them randomly with no specific pattern but now i added these new files that start with column-. Hoever, since i already difened the metatags for the old files i wonder where should iinclude them in your code.

Comment: If amending the old meta tags is possible, i'll suggest you do that.This will provide more consistency across the code base and also will be easy to manage in future!:)